# C++ and "telephaty" method calling

Tags: c++, objective-c

i am newbie in C++, but need add some function to one project - https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX
But , for example, in HTMLRenderer/text.cc is method drawString, is called in running program, but i don't see in whole project call to this function. How works this call "telephaty" in C++? Trying find any informations, but after fast-read half book about C++ don't have more info.

Comment: Try to debug the program, setting breakpoint on this method and checking the backtrace.

Comment: This is like trying to extend an oil well by 500 feet on your own when you've never even used a power drill before and only briefly skimmed the 5,000 page manual for the drillhead.

Comment: not exactly - i know assembler, basic, php, javascript and little bit java;) and this is last thing to complete ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach to the program in a debugger, and add a breakpoint in that method. When the breakpoint is hit, you will see the call stack.

Comment: this is stack:
#0  in waitpid () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  in print_trace() ()
#2  in pdf2htmlEX::HTMLRenderer::drawString(GfxState*, GooString*) ()
#3  in Gfx::doShowText at Gfx.cc:4033
#4  in Gfx::opShowSpaceText at Gfx.cc:3828
#5  in Gfx::go at Gfx.cc:715
#6  in Gfx::display at Gfx.cc:681
#7  in Page::displaySlice at Page.cc:523
#8  in Page::display at Page.cc:451
#9  in pdf2htmlEX::HTMLRenderer::process(PDFDoc*) ()
#10 in main ()

Comment: but in HTMLRenderer::process method is calling 3rd party libs and from this libs is called drawString method? how is possible affect this? is not transparent from my angle of view, or is any mechanism how work this?

Comment: there is some kind of 3rd party framework involved here, which the app extends by implementing the drawString method